# How to handle SQL query result caching

Tags: sql, perl, caching

In a Perl program I cache SQL request result to speed up the program.

I see two common way to do that:

- Create a hash using the query as index to cache result, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757110/is-there-a-way-to-caching-mechanism-for-classdbi/1518501#1518501)
- Create a hash with but 2 index, first is the list of used table, second is where clause

I today used the 2nd option because it's easier to clean the cache for a given set of table when you know they have been changed.

My problem is to handle the cache cleaning, today most select query I do are against table with very few change. So when I run an update/delete/... I just clean up the hash table part that cache result for this table.

This has few impact on performance as I rarely have to clean the part of the hash that is often used.
But now for a program with more often update/delete on most table, this make my cache much less efficient as I often have to clean it.

How to deal with that ? My current cache system is quite simple, Cache::Memcached::Fast is quite complex. Do you have a solution that would be more efficient that mine but still quite simple ?

Comment: For what database?  I can't speak for the embedded ones, but the major players already provide caching - google "hard vs soft parse" for more info.

Comment: Postgre, MySQL, etc. They provide caching but adding a caching in the software for very often called query is even fast and avoid query overload to the database server

Comment: Query overload?  Databases handle 1,000+ users simultaneously.  You're creating a solution to a problem that never existed.  Connection pooling I can understand, but not query caching on the application side.

Comment: I seem to be saying this a lot lately, but it never ceases to amaze me how readily people will assume that databases - a class of software specifically designed and optimized to handle huge volumes of concurrent queries - will fall over dead if asked to do more than a handful of queries per second.

Comment: "Databases handle 1,000+ users simultaneously", put a DB on a Pentium Pro 100Mhz with 36MB of ram and see... It really depends. Number of simultaneous request is more important than simultaneous user in most case. Anyway even with the best processor and lots of ram there is a limit where the DB is overloaded... put 50 front end doing lots of query for 1 DB and you will see (even if processor follow, network can become overloaded). If caching in the software can save you a costy DB server each 50 front end with a minimal effort in the software why don't do it? Why do you think memcached exist?

Answer (score 1):

One approach I use for caching data that isn't likely to change (e.g. configuration data) is to use memoization, via the excellent [Memoize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Memoize) module.  I wrap the sql query in a function where I pass in the bind parameters and the table name, and memoize that function.

```
use Memoize;

sub get_config_for_foo
{
     my ($table, $field1, $field2) @_;

     # generate my sql query here, using table, field1 and field2...

     return $result;

}
memoize(get_config_for_foo);
```

You could also use a caching strategy in memcache or something similar; check out [Tie::Cache::LRU](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-Cache-LRU/lib/Tie/Cache/LRU.pm) for a good implementation for this.